# Portions of inline SVG not rendering in Firefox until selected or re-scrolled

Tags: html, css, svg, firefox

I have some inline SVG elements exported from PlantUML on a web page. They display properly in Chrome, Edge, and Safari on iOS, but in Firefox parts of them will sometimes not render until I either select them or scroll them off the page and back on. This also does not occur if I include the SVG using an `<img>` tag, but this doesn't render properly in Safari.

The SVGs have a "width" attribute, as suggested here: [Rendering inline SVG in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353443/rendering-inline-svg-in-firefox)

Example:

[image]

[image]

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentStyleType="text/css" height="58px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:105px;height:58px;background:#00000000;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 105 58" width="105px" zoomAndPan="magnify">
<defs>
    <filter height="300%" id="fd8xeq7sn9ue2" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1">
    <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/>
    <feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/>
    <feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/>
    </filter>
</defs>
<g>
<!--MD5=[3c439da1e0ca43de06b2478d62879606]
entity ListDog-->
    <g id="elem_ListDog">
    <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fd8xeq7sn9ue2)" height="37.6094" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.5;" width="84" x="7" y="7"/>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="64" x="17" y="31.5332">List&lt;Dog&gt;</text>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

This is the CSS I am using to resize and center it in the page. The `<svg>` element is embedded within a `<figure>` element.

```
figure.figure {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    margin: auto;
}

figure.figure svg,
figure.figure img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Full HTML sample:

```
<figure class="figure">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentStyleType="text/css" height="58px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:105px;height:58px;background:#00000000;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 105 58" width="105px" zoomAndPan="magnify">
<defs>
    <filter height="300%" id="fd8xeq7sn9ue2" width="300%" x="-1" y="-1">
    <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2.0"/>
    <feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="blurOut2" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .4 0"/>
    <feOffset dx="4.0" dy="4.0" in="blurOut2" result="blurOut3"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut3" mode="normal"/>
    </filter>
</defs>
<g>
<!--MD5=[3c439da1e0ca43de06b2478d62879606]
entity ListDog-->
    <g id="elem_ListDog">
    <rect fill="#FEFECE" filter="url(#fd8xeq7sn9ue2)" height="37.6094" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.5;" width="84" x="7" y="7"/>
    <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="64" x="17" y="31.5332">List&lt;Dog&gt;</text>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>


<figcaption>
    Possible Datapaths
    <span class="sources">
        <a class="source" href="DataPaths.plantuml" target="_blank" title="Click to download figure source code.">(Source)</a>
        <a class="source" href="DataPaths.svg" target="_blank" title="Click to download embedded SVG figure.">(Download)</a>
    </span>
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

Update: it appears to be related to shadowing. I removed the shadowing on the box with `skinparam Shadowing false` and the issue went away. I would prefer to keep shadowing if possible, but it's a lead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentStyleType="text/css" height="449px" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="width:1280px;height:449px;background:#00000000;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1280 449" width="1280px" zoomAndPan="magnify">
  <defs/>
    <g id="elem_ListDog">
      <rect fill="#FEFECE" height="37.6094" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.5;" width="84" x="521" y="29"/>
      <text fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="14" lengthAdjust="spacing" textLength="64" x="531" y="53.5332">List&lt;Dog&gt;</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please format the code so it is readable.

Comment: Is this really the smallest example you could create?

Comment: I have now reduced the image down to a single box.

Comment: The `<filter>` element mixes unitless numbers and percentages for sizing the filter primitives region. Theoretically they should be equipotent, but maybe it helps to make them match. Try either setting the `x` and `y` attributes to `"-100%"`, or the `width` and `height` to `"3"`.

Comment: @ccprog Yes, that fixed the problem! If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't reproduce the problem, one thing stands out: The `<filter>` element mixes unitless numbers and percentages for sizing the filter effects region. Theoretically [they should be equipotent](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/coords.html#ObjectBoundingBoxUnits), but maybe it helps to make them match. Try either setting the `x` and `y` attributes to "-100%", or the `width` and `height` to "3".

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce this bug, but maybe swapping the SVG filter for a CSS filter helps:

```css
rect, ellipse {
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 2px #0006);
}
```

Comment: I had hoped to be able to use filters within the SVG, but the problem does appear to be related to them. Applying this CSS rule to `figure.figure.plantuml svg>g>g>rect:first-child` (and to ellipse) did fix the issue though, so it's a workaround for now.

Comment: You can use CSS inside SVGs using the `<style>` tag, but since you're inlining the SVGs anyway, I think using global CSS isn't a bad approach. If you only use filters for drop shadows, you can use the attribute selector `[filter]`. If you can edit the original files I'd remove the filters in `<defs>` and replace `filter="..."` on all elements with `class="shadow"` and apply the CSS filter to this class